# Selecting all rows which contain values greater than a percentage of Average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame`, which have 3 numeric columns `A,B,C`. I need to extract only those rows where values in all these 3 columns `A,B,C` is more than 40% of their **row average**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['AA',10,8,12],['BB',10,2,18],['CC',10,6,14]],
                  columns=['ID','A', 'B', 'C'])
print(df)
    ID  A   B   C
0   AA  10  8   12
1   BB  10  2   18
2   CC  10  6   14
```

I mean the following: For Row 1, the mean of A,B,C is 30/3=10, and I want that in Row 1 all values, be it A or B or C should be more than 40% of 10, i.e; 4. Similarly, for Row 2 and Row 3. In case even one element is less than that, we remove that row.

**My attempt:** I used [`any()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) function, but that does't help me when involving average of columns. I always get empty `DF`.

```
df = df[(df[['A','B','C']] > (0.4*df[['A','B','C']].mean(axis=1))).all(1)]
print(df)
ID  A   B   C
```

I was expecting this:

```
    ID  A   B   C
0   AA  10  8   12
2   CC  10  6   14
```

The average of all rows is 10, so if I would have hardcoded it, it would work, like this:

```
df[(df[['A','B','C']] > 0.4*10).all(1)]
```

How can I do this dynamically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
a = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].values

df[(a > 0.4*(a.mean(1)[:, None])).all(1)]
```

Output:

```
   ID   A  B   C
0  AA  10  8  12
2  CC  10  6  14
```

Comment: I think this code will not work because `a.mean()` will give the mean of entire data. Where as what we want is to compare mean of the individual arrays with their respective means.

Comment: You mean: the comparison should be with the mean of each column?

Comment: I mean the following: For Row 1, the mean of `A,B,C` is 30/3=10, and I want that in Row 1 all values, be it A or B or C should be more than 40% of 10, i.e; 4. Similarly, for Row 2 and Row 3.

Comment: No, the comparision should be made with the mean of each row and not column.

Comment: I guess my updated solution solves your problem, @cph_sto.

Comment: Let me delve into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use, [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) after comparing each value to 40% of the columns [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), and aggregating with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html). [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) (`>`) is used for easy handling of the comparison:

```
tmp = df.drop(columns='ID')

out = df.loc[tmp.gt(tmp.mean(axis=1).mul(0.4), axis=0).all(axis=1)]
```

Alternative:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df.loc[df[cols].gt(df[cols].mean(axis=1).mul(0.4), axis=0).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   ID   A  B   C
0  AA  10  8  12
2  CC  10  6  14
```

Comment: I have a small Question. When you do  `df[cols].mean()`, does it not calculate along `axis=0`, I mean column wise, rather than row wise? Normally, if we do `df[[cols]].mean()`, we get a series of index `A,B,C` with corresponding means of the columns.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. If you want to compare to each value to their row mean, then you need `df[cols].gt(df[cols].mean(axis=1), axis=0).all(axis=1)`. In your example, however, no row matches this condition.

Comment: I tried it on a bigger dataset, the code in your answer doesn't work.

Comment: @cph_sto can you provide an example? Of course you need to slice which I haven' included in my comment

Comment: I wrote clarification on @PaulS's answer. Does that help you to understand the issue? let me know. Thanks

Comment: @cph_sto can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76703126/edit) your answer with those details? It will be better for everyone to see (and will have a nicer formatting). See my updated answer for the filtering by row.

Comment: Many many thanks for your kind help. I had to do some checks and your answer works great. Have a nice day.